# Forecasting for time series forecasting

Tags: data-analysis, statistics

I am looking for software, reading material or tutorials to solve the following kind of problems:

I have a database with the following structure:

| DATE | PARKING-NAME | NCARS |

I need to predict the number of cars in a specific parking based on the historical data that I've collected. Is there a *simple* way of doing this using some kind of forecasting software? Or do I need to write an algorithm myself?

Thank you

Comment: I am surprized that you got no reply. You just need to extrapolate. IIRC, MS Excel can do this (so Libre Office probably can too). You just draw a chart and ask it to add a trend line. Would that help?

Comment: @Mawg thanks for the answer! I guess it would help, but you are saying that extrapolating with excel is the same as applying a forecasting algorithm?

Comment: Well, I don't know the underlying algorithm, and I don't know enough mathematics to say whether there is a standard formula.  Since Libre Office is open source, you could check the code for comments :-) or ask somewhere on S.E.  WHen I have used Excelin the past, it certainly looked good. If you do't get a better answer, try Libre Office and check the predictions against real world results.